# Can I nest presentation model objcts (PMOs) in linkki?

Tags: linkki

I want to build a section in my user interface that consists of a vertical layout showing some basic data followed by table. The standard way in linkki is to have one section to display the basic data and one for the table. Can I group these two sections into one?

For example like this

MySectionPmo (Caption)

- BasicDataPmo
- MyTablePmo

If yes, how is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not perfectly supported yet but you can do it using @UINestedComponent which is in a seperate module:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.linkki-framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>linkki-core-vaadin8-nestedcomponent</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Your main section may look like this:

```
@UISection(caption = "My Section")
public class MySectionPmo {

    @UINestedComponent(position = 10)
    public BasicDataPmo getBasicData() {
        return new BasicDataPmo();
    }

    @UINestedComponent(position = 20)
    public MyTablePmo getTesTablePmo() {
        return new MyTablePmo();
    }

}
```

In `BasicDataPmo` you could simply use `@UIVerticalLayout` or `@UIFormLayout`. Your table PMO must be annotated with `@UISection`.

Drawbacks:

- There is no support for creating a table without a section layout at the moment. That means your table is wrapped by some useless layouts which hopefuly have no visual effects
- The section always creates a two column grid layout to have one column for the labels although there are no labels at the nested components